# React native sticky notification call like Whatsapp with Agora

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, agora.io

Hi everyone I'm using react-native firebase to send notification to users. Also  using the Agora for online call.Both works fine.

I want to make a sticky notification like whatsapp ,send user to call and it will continuosly sticks at notificaiton header untill call ends.

How to do or send notification like this. Thank you.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you've attempted and we'll take a look!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a call Notification just like what's app
you can achieve it using push notification in android and process it in background (remember only send data in push notification payload and set "priority :high" incase of android)
for achieving the same functionality in ios you can use
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-voip-call
and configure VoIP token for ios in xcode